# Windows Phone string to color

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

There is no System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter in Windows Phone (or Silverlight) so I need another way to take a string containing a color name e.g. "Red" and generate a Color object from it.

I found this possibility but it doesn't work as colorType.GetProperty always returns null.

```
public static Color ConvertFromString(string colorString)
{
    Color retval = Colors.Transparent;

    Type colorType = (typeof(Colors));

    if (colorType.GetProperty(colorString) != null)
    {
        object o = colorType.InvokeMember(colorString,
            BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null); 

        if (o != null)
        {
            retval =  (Color)o;
        }
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I like both answers and both work fine. The only reason I didn't mark the XAML one as the answer was that it was not case insensitive. If colorName is "RED" it does not work. Not sure which is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
public static Color GetColor(String ColorName)
{
    Type colors = typeof(System.Windows.Media.Colors);
    foreach(var prop in colors.GetProperties())
    {
        if(prop.Name == ColorName)
            return ((System.Windows.Media.Color)prop.GetValue(null, null));
    }

    throw new Exception("No color found");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not tried it on WP, but in SL you can hijack XAML for this (and also for `SolidColorBrush` and such):

```
    private Color StringToColor(string colorName)
    {
        string xaml = string.Format("<Color xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">{0}</Color>", colorName);
        try { return (Color)XamlReader.Load(xaml); }
        catch { return Colors.Transparent; }
    }
```